# Propositional Calculus and associated problems

Tags: propositional-calculus

What I'm trying to prove: $P\to (Q\to S)$

Given Premises: $P\to (Q\to R)$ and $Q\to (R\to S)$

My approach:

$$Q\to (R\to S)$$
$$(Q\land R)\to S$$
$$(R\land Q)\to S$$
$$R\to (Q\to S)$$
also from the premises,

$$P\to (Q\to R)$$
$$(P\land Q)\to R$$
$$\dot{.\hspace{.075in}.}(P\land Q)\to (Q\to S) $$

I'm kinda stuck on what to do after this.

Should I do $\neg(P\land Q)\lor (\neg Q\lor S)$  ?

It seems like I'm beating around a bush.

Comment: Have you proved the Deduction Theorem yet?

Comment: Why should I prove that?

Comment: It is one of the first things you prove about the Propositional Calculus. It would make this problem easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying the axiom $[A \rightarrow (B \rightarrow C)] \rightarrow [(A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow (A \rightarrow C)]$ to your last line will give you $(P \wedge Q) \rightarrow S$.

Comment: Is there an axiom like that?

Comment: There is in the system I use, any system you're using should have something equivalent to it at least.